# Why is my Perl / HTML code not working for apache2?

Tags: perl, apache2

I am trying to make a selection system on a webpage that has 5 options and each of these 5 options does something different, using a Linux system with Perl and Apache2 installed.

The menu page is working but whenever I try to access any option it does not work.
The error says "Internal server error The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request".
I had these error before with the menu file but it was a syntax error.

The main files are index.cgi and indexManager.cgi.
Index.cgi has the introduction menu with the options and indexManager has the functions for the options selection.

Index.cgi Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
 
print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n";
print "<html>";
print "<head>";
print   "<title>Proyecto 3 UNIX: PERL, APACHE</title>";
print "</head>";
print "<body>";
print   "<h1>Welcome to Magnum System Check</h1>";
print "<br>";
print "<form action = indexManager.cgi method='POST'>";
print "<br>";
print   "<input type='radio' name='subject' value='process'> View my process";
print "<br>";
print   "<input type='radio' name='subject' value='calendar'> View my calendar";
print "<br>";
print   "<input type='radio' name='subject' value='location'> View my location";
print "<br>";
print   "<input type='radio' name='subject' value='user'> View users connected to my system";
print "<br>";
print   "<input type='radio' name='subject' value='find'> Find a file or directory";
print "<br>";
print   "<input type='submit' value='Select Subject'>";
print "</form>";
print "</body>";
print "</html>";
```

indexManager.cgi code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
 
local ($buffer, @pairs, $pair, $name, $value, %FORM);
# Read in text
$ENV{REQUEST_METHOD} =~ tr/a-z/A-Z/;
if ($ENV{REQUEST_METHOD} eq 'POST')
{
    read(STDIN, $buffer, $ENV{CONTENT_LENGTH});
} else {
    $buffer = $ENV{QUERY_STRING};
}
# SPLIT INFORMATION INTO NAME/VALUE PAIRS
 
@pairs = split(/&/, $buffer);
foreach $pair (@pairs)
{
    ($name, $value) = split(/*/, $pair);
    $value =~ tr/*/ /;
    $value =~ s/%(..)/pack(*C*, hex($1))/eg;
    $FORM{$name} = $value;
}
$subject = $FORM{subject};
print *Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n";
 
if ($subject eq 'process')
{
    use CGI;
    $cgi = new CGI;
 
    @output = './text';
 
    print "<html>";
    print "<body>";
 
    print "<table style='width:100%'>";
    foreach $i(@output)
    {
     print "<tr>";
     print " <td?$i</td>";
     print "</tr>";
    }
    print "</table>";
    print "<br>";
    print "<br>";
    print $cgi->a({-href=>'index.cgi'},"return to main menu");
 
    print "</body>";
    print "</html>";
}
 
if ($subject eq 'calendar')
{
    use CGI;
    $cgi = new CGI;
    print 'My calendar';
    print '<br>'    
 
    $myCal = CALENDAR->new(); #VIEW CURRENT MONTH
    print $myCal->create();$cal = 'cal';
 
    print '<br>';
    print '<br>';
    print $cgi->a({-href=>'index.cgi'},"return to main menu");
}
 
if ($subject eq 'location')
{
    use CGI;
    $cgi = new CGI;
 
 
    print 'Favor entrar la direccion relacionada a su localidad';
    print '<br>';
 
    print '<FORM action="geoCoder.cgi" method="POST">';
    print '<select name="dropdown1">';
    print '<option value=" " selected>none </option>';
    print '<option value="urb.">Urb</option>';
    print '<option value="bo">Bo</option>';
    print '<option value="jard.">Jard</option>';
 
    print '</select>';
    print '<input type="text" name="lugar"> <br>';
    print 'Num :<input type="text" name="numero"> <br>';
    
    print '<select name="dropdown2">';
    print '<option value=" " selected>none </option>';
    print '<option value="calle">calle</option>';
    print '<option value="ave">Ave</option>';
    print '<option value="carr">Carr</option>';
 
    print '</select>';
 
    print '<input type="text" name="nombre_calle"> <br>';
    print 'Pueblo: <input type="text" name="pueblo"> <br>';
    print 'Estado: <input type="text" name="estado"> <br>';
    print 'Zip code: <input type="text" name="zip"> <br>';
 
    print '<input type="submit" value="Submit">';
    print '</FORM>';
 
 
    print '<br>';
    print '<br>';
    print $cgi->a({-href=>'index.cgi'},"return to main menu");
}
 
if ($subject eq 'user')
{
    use CGI;
    $cgi = new CGI;
 
    @output = 'who';
 
    print "<html>";
    print "<body>";
 
    print "<table style='width:100%' >";
    foreach $i(@output)
    {
     print "<tr>";
     print " <td>$i</td>";
     print "</tr>";
    }
    print "</table>";
    print "<br>";
    print "<br>";
    print $cgi->a({-href=>'index.cgi'},"return to main menu");
 
    print "</body>";
    print "</html>";
}
 
if ($subject eq 'find')
{
    use CGI;
    $cgi = new CGI;
 
    print $cgi->filefield(-name=>'uploaded_file',-default=>'starting value',-size=>50,-maxlength=>80);
    print "<br>";
    print "<br>";
    print $cgi->a({-href=>'index.cgi},"return to main menu");
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUJRH.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuxOR.png)

Comment: 1) Don't post text as just images. 2) What error is in your log?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.</p>
<p>Please contact the server administrator at
 webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred,
 and the actions you performed just before this error.</p>
<p>More information about this error may be available
in the server error log.</p>
<hr>

Comment: No, the error produced by the program, in your logs. Not what the server sent. And info that's missing from your question should be added to your question, not posted a as comment.

Answer (score 1):

You should initally test a minimal code sample and progress from it.

Please try to not pollute the code with **print** statements, usually one **print** statement sufficient.

Perhaps it would be more preferable to generate web page in a variable and at the very end of *cgi* code dump it out.

*index.cgi*

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print 
"Content-type:text/html

<html>
        <head>
                <title>Proyecto 3 UNIX: PERL, APACHE</title>
        </head>
        <body>
                <h1>Welcome to Magnum System Check</h1>
                <br>
                <form action = indexManager.cgi method='POST'>
                        <br>
                        <input type='radio' name='subject' value='process'> View my process
                        <br>
                        <input type='radio' name='subject' value='calendar'> View my calendar
                        <br>
                        <input type='radio' name='subject' value='location'> View my location
                        <br>
                        <input type='radio' name='subject' value='user'> View users connected to my system
                        <br>
                        <input type='radio' name='subject' value='find'> Find a file or directory
                        <br>
                        <input type='submit' value='Select Subject'>
                </form>
        </body>
</html>
";
```

*indexManager.cgi*

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $page =
"Content-type:text/html

<html>
        <head>
                <title>
                        Test page
                </title>
        </head>
        <body>
                Passed arguments...

                <table border=1>
";

while( my($k,$v) = each %ENV ) {
        $page .= "<tr><td>$k</td><td>$v</td>";
}

$page .=
"
                </table>
        </body>
</html>
";

print $page;
```

Let's extract parameters from **%ENV** variable

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my(@data, %param);

if( $ENV{REQUEST_METHOD} eq 'POST' ) {
    my $query = '';
    read( STDIN, $query, $ENV{CONTENT_LENGTH} ) == $ENV{CONTENT_LENGTH}
        or return undef;
    push @data, split /&/, $query;
}

for( @data ) {
    if( /=/ ) {
        my($k,$v) = split /=/, $_;
        $param{$k} = $v;
    } else {
        $param{$_} = 1;
    }
}

my $page =
"Content-type:text/html

<html lang='en'>
        <meta charset='utf8'/>
        <head>
                <title>
                     Test page
                </title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <pre>
"
. Dumper(\%param) .
"
            </pre>
        </body>
</html>
";

print $page;
```

NOTE: if your *indexManager.cgi* will produce any error before **Content-type:text/html** web page will not be rendered